# Css3 Multi-Column with column-count in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a layout that work like the css3 multicolumn with column-count: 4 functionality in such that the layout is fluid. 
My layout is as folowing:
for small device:

```
control1
control2
control3
control4
```

For bigger device: (look a the order)

```
control1  control3
control2  control4
```

Then for extra big screen i could have

```
control1  control2  control3  control4
```

This keeps the order of the control so that if i want to use my existing keys (tab index) it works perfectly.

Please look in explorer how this work with css3

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p38etxoq/9/#&togetherjs=NrSEGyILNH)

Comment: [link](    http://jsfiddle.net/p38etxoq/9/#&togetherjs=NrSEGyILNH)

Comment: I do really want to know if this is even possible with bootstrap or any other framework

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: haztbh, grid does not keep the order of the controls. Think about a win form where user alway fill up form in an order with tab index keys. The order need to be the same vertically , then horizontally after.

Comment: That's not an issue with bootstrap that's an issue with the way you have decided to do the order. Bootstrap orders in the logical way. You probably need to rethink that aspect of it. Remember, this as a website, not a win form. If those are strict requirements then you will have to come up with something custom yourself.

Comment: Agreed 100% , that was my assumption but wanted to make sure that i am not trying to do something that exist already

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your problem is not with positioning the controls in a shown way, but with the order of their tab index?

Comment: Both. However let s think more web than window. I finally decide using the grid

Answer (score 4):

You can define all this using the grid system right: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). defining the screen size: `xs`: extra-small, `sm`: small and `md`: for medium, `lg`: for large. Right now i just decided to use `sm`: for small device, `lg` for extra big screen in your case, nest the columns

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">control1</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">control2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">control3</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">control4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is that when control1(field security make that user can not see that field), control3 does not shift to the first column

Comment: oh i see what you mean. Let me work on that for a second. @FasoService

Comment: i think you can achieve that with playing around with classes and Js change the class depending on the settings and I don't quite get what you mean by security settings too thanks@FasoService

Comment: I meant some uses will not see all controls based on permission. SO let say control2 will not show, for me, for exemple, control3 need take its place

Answer (score 4):

[Pure css option here](http://jsfiddle.net/p38etxoq/18/embedded/result/) I would not recomment to use table tags anymore, you can better manipulate tables with "display: table" and change it for a different view as you desire. [tables without table](http://www.mattboldt.com/kicking-ass-with-display-table/#tables-without-the-table)

```css
.container {
  column-width: 280px;
  -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 4;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: block;
}

.table-cell {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description1</div>
    </div>
    <div  class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Label4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Editor4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Description4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who have stubbled across this page as I did you may find `column-width` will work.

```
<div style="column-width: 250px;">
    <div>Control 1</div>
    <div>Control 2</div>
    <div>Control 3</div>
    <div>Control 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For "Lg (<1000px)" on Chrome 85 the layout with 4 items is the same as "Md (<750px)". With 5 items the layout is 3 columns, first column with 1, 2, second column with 3, 4 and the third column has just 5. I checked this just because the layout you have looks odd ('sorted' across... while the others are all 'sorted' in column)

Comment: @user2845090 You are correct. I based this off an example I had and didn't test the code fully. I have updated the answer and this should work for the OP question and hopefully will be a starting point for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout will solve your problem

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr))">
    <div>Control 1</div>
    <div>Control 2</div>
    <div>Control 3</div>
    <div>Control 4</div>
    <div>Control 5</div>
    <div>Control 6</div>
    <div>Control 7</div>
    <div>Control 8</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr))">
    <div>Control 1</div>
    <div>Control 2</div>
    <div>Control 3</div>
    <div>Control 4</div>
    <div>Control 5</div>
    <div>Control 6</div>
    <div>Control 7</div>
    <div>Control 8</div>
</div>
```